# a small issue with mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax, php

I'm recently started to learn php & mysql,
i wanna know what's wrong with this

```
function show(){
$query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM family ");
if (!$query) {
    die("invalid query ".mysql_error());
}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo    "<tr>
 line 24 ===><td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

as you can see i have a function for show my data fields,
and i have a table in another page that i want to by just including & calling the function,my variables appear in the table,but i keep getting this stupid error:
help plz

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\lib.php on line 24**

for those who wanna suggest this below code:

```
echo    "<tr>
            <td>". $row['id'] ."</td>
            <td>". $row['name'] ."</td>
            <td>". $row['lname'] ."</td>
        </tr>";
```

i did try this and it works but it wont show my date in the table rows 
my purpose of this is that i want it to show my each data variables in a table row, any other good way you know?

Comment: Have you noticed the big red box in the PHP documentation of `mysql_` functions that says you shouldn't use them anymore?

Comment: and where is line 24?

Comment: can you explain more?!

Comment: @user2668542 - what exactly is it now outputting? Can you put a `var_dump($row);` inside your while loop to see exactly what you're getting back from the database?

Comment: @andrewsi- http://s21.postimg.org/l28y2hitj/image.png this is my output when just write echo $row['id'];

Comment: use PDO [forget the mysql extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>` to `<td>".$row['id']."</td>`

You're trying to bring php code inside a string, which won't work. Just concatinate the strings using the 'dot' operator. Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more information.

Edit as requested:

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "<tr>
    <td>".$row['id']."</td>
    <td>".$row['name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['lname']."</td>
  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: i did try it but i want it wont build the table rows

Comment: You have to do this at every line where you inserted the php tags (`<?php`) inside your string :)

Comment: my purpose of this is that i want it to show my each data variables in a table row, any other good way you know?

Comment: See edit. The following will give you a table, where each row contains a record from your table in the database. If that's not your expected output, you have to be way clearer in your questions.

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/l28y2hitj/image.png
this happens
no table :(

Comment: Do you have a `"` somewhere inside of a name?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing, you need to just close and reopen your PHP tags:

```
function show(){
$query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM family ");
if (!$query) {
    die("invalid query ".mysql_error());
}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
```

Alternately, without opening and closing:

```
function show(){
$query=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM family ");
if (!$query) {
    die("invalid query ".mysql_error());
}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo    "<tr>
            <td>". $row['id'] ."</td>
            <td>". $row['name'] ."</td>
            <td>". $row['lname'] ."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: it show's the db fields in a row not a row in the table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function show()
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `family`");
    //check if query failed
    if (!$query) {
        die("invalid query ".mysql_error());
    }

    //if there are more than 0 rows in table, we create the table
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        echo "<table>";

        //loop thru array and create table rows
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
           echo    "<tr>
                       <td>". $row['id'] ."</td>
                       <td>". $row['name'] ."</td>
                       <td>". $row['lname'] ."</td>
                    </tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
   }
   else //no rows, we display an error
   {
       echo 'Table is empty';
   }
}
```

also use mysqli_* because mysql_* is depreciated

Comment: it wont build the table rows :(

Comment: updated answer. what do you mean it won't build rows? any errors?